# Output parameters not readable when used with a DataReader

Tags: .net, stored-procedures, ado.net, parameters, datareader

When using a `DataReader` object to access data from a database (such as SQL Server) through stored procedures, any output parameter added to the Command object before executing are not being filled after reading.  I can read row data just fine, as well as all input parameters, but not output ones.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is due to the "by design" nature of [DataReaders](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbdatareader.aspx).  Any parameters marked as `ParameterDirection.Output` won't be "filled" until the DataReader has been closed.  While still open, all Output parameters will more than likely just come back `null`.

The full Microsoft KB article concerning this can be viewed [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308621).